# Appyling Gradle signing plugin, without requiring a GPG keyring

Tags: gradle, sign, gradle-plugin, maven-central

I am following the instructions at http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html to use Gradle to upload artifacts to the Maven Central Repository.  The instructions work.  Examples appear at https://github.com/plume-lib/options/blob/master/build.gradle and https://github.com/plume-lib/bcel-util/blob/master/build.gradle .

My problem is that it results in a buildfile that other developers cannot use.

The Gradle signing plugin (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html) requires a `gradle.properties` file with `signing.keyId`, `signing.password`, and `signing.secretKeyRingFile`, where the latter points to a valid GPG keyring.  The plugin terminates the build with an error if the file doesn't exist or is not valid.

But signing is only needed when uploading artifacts to Maven Central.
I want any user to be able to run the gradle buildfile (except for actually uploading to Maven Central), even if they do not have a GPG keyring.

How can I achieve this?

Here are some things I have tried:

1. Split the gradle file into parts.  (This is what is shown in the linked examples.)  This requires two changes.

   - Change the main buildfile into a build script.  (It can still be invoked from the command line).  One gross thing about this is that only a gradle buildfile can contain a `plugins { ... }` block, and referring to a plugin outside the `plugins { ... }` block is verbose and ugly, as at the bottom of (say) https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.sherter.google-java-format or
   - Create another buildfile, used only for signing, that uses `apply from:` to include the main one.

   Question: Is there a way to do this without the ugly buildscript block?
2. Commit a dummy keyring to the repository, refer to it in the local gradle.properties, and the user's `~/gradle.properties` can override it for any user who wants to upload to Maven Central.  A problem is that using a local pathname yields a gradle warning.
   Question: Is there a way to do this without a gradle warning?
3. Use conditional signing (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html).  In my experiments, this does not help.  Even on a gradle execution where the artifacts are not signed, the signing plugin still requires the GPG keyring to exist.
   Question: Can conditional signing be used to avoid the need for a GPG keyring?

Question: Is there a better way to achieve my goals than the above possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a section on ["Conditional Signing"](https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:conditional_signing) which is exactly what you need here.
And you can even make that condition check that the required properties are indeed available to the build.

Comment: Point #3 in my question points out that conditional signing does not work, at least not as described in the manual.

Comment: That's really strange, I have authored the Ehcache 3 build and it is working as documented, there are no definitions of the required properties in the build nor in my local ~/.gradle/gradle.properties - see https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/EhDeploy.groovy#L53